# Can I use a CASE expression within a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure how to do write query in sql. 

 
This is what I have tried so far.

```
where
  case 
       when a.book_id like 'AB%' then a.book_id = b.school_id,   --1   
       when a.book_id like 'CB%' then a.book_id = b.college_id.  --2
  end
```

**case 1 and 2 explanation.** 
1- I believe is good.
2- when `a.book` start with letter CB e.g `CBQ123` then just take `Q123` = `b.college_id`.
        
 b.college_id don't have CB in front of it.

**Edit to add example**

```
select 
       a.Name,
       a.ID,
       a.Due,
       b.school_id,
       b.college_id
from Student a and FinishedStudent b
where
  case 
       when a.book_id like 'AB%' then a.book_id = b.school_id,   --1   
       when a.book_id like 'CB%' then a.book_id = b.college_id.  --2
  end
```

if a.book = CBQ111 then Q111 is in FinishedStudent table not CBQ11,so I need to just compare last 3 character.

**edit with case 2 example**

```
   when a.book_id ='CBQ111' then a.book_id(Q111) = b.college_id.  --2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and an example result set like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358842/how-to-get-distinct-rows-with-max-value/). You specify SQL Server in the title but MySQL and Oracle in the tags. Can you clarify which product you are using?

Comment: why cant you do the same in `select` part of the query?

Comment: Why is book_id ever equal to a school_id or a college_id? I see serious data model problems here. Also why is it tagged both SQL Server and Oracle? The syntax for the two platforms will likely be different.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, including what you want to happen when a.book_id is not like AB or CB.

Comment: if a.book = CBQ111 then Q111 is in FinishedStudent table not CBQ11,so I need to just compare last 3 character.

Comment: Please read: http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to explain better next time. I tried best to word it out.

Comment: We're much better at reading sample data and desired results than word problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a minor syntax issue. In T-SQL, `CASE` is an expression that returns a value, so you need to compare the output to something - it is not a control-of-flow statement like it is in other languages like VB.

```
where a.book_id = case 
       when a.book_id like 'AB%' then b.school_id    --1   
       when a.book_id like 'CB%' then b.college_id   --2
  end
```

Based on the scrambling of word problems added in comments, perhaps what you're actually after is this:

```
WHERE (a.book_id LIKE 'AB%' AND a.book_id = b.school_id)
   OR (a.book_id LIKE 'CB%' AND SUBSTRING(a.book_id, 3, 255) = b.college_id)
```

There are other ways to write that last line but if book_id has an index the LIKE filter is probably still helpful.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, then I asked myself: isn't an `ELSE` required here? What if `a.book_id` doesn't match any of those conditions?

Comment: @bfavaretto then the row isn't returned. We can only work with the information we've been given.

Comment: So you mean `CASE` would return `NULL` or something like that in this case? That would make sense.

Comment: Right, and a.book_id = NULL would return unknown which, for all intents and purposes, is equivalent to false, which means discard the row.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for fixing syntax, but here is real problem. if `a.book` = CBQ111 then Q111 is in FinishedStudent table not CBQ11,so I need to just compare last 3 character.

Comment: @Mogil edit your question. Show sample data and desired results. Please don't litter answers with comments describing word problems about what you want.

Comment: I need help fixing 2nd case, when a.book_id start with `CB` then cutoff CB and remaning part of it = b.college_id. how can I code that?

Comment: Yes, that is where, I am trying to get to, but I someone asked for example, I couldn't word it any better.

Comment: Do you mean `then`? instead of `AND`?

Comment: @Mogil I don't understand. Do you mean in the second query? No, I don't mean `then`. There is no `CASE` there.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: to correct an issue and clean up code.

You can put it in the WHERE clause but I prefer to put it in the join.

```
select 
       a.Name,
       a.ID,
       a.Due,
       b.school_id,
       b.college_id
from Student a
  join FinishedStudent b on a.book_id = 
    case 
       when a.book_id like 'AB%' then b.school_id,   --1   
       when a.book_id like 'CB%' then b.college_id.  --2
    end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct to me; it seems like a boolean expression. You need to compare the output to something.

Comment: Thanks, was a typo. I looked into it a bit more and made some edits.